# Changing foreground color of <option> element while selected?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently working with a `<select>` element with an indeterminate number of `<option>` children.

I have written some simple jQuery that adds or removes the `.tagged` class to the currently selected element.  This css class only changes the foreground color of the element.

The trouble I'm having is that the change in color is only visible once the user selects a different `<option>` within the list.  So long as the current `<option>` remains selected, it has white foreground and blue background.

Is anyone able to point me in the correct direction for altering this?  I'm assuming it's some css trick I don't know just yet.

Edit (to include code):
Here's the select element:`<select size="4" name="ctl00$Searcher$lbResults" id="ctl00_Searcher_lbResults" class="search-results">`

The option elements are nothing special, just an attribute for their value.

This is the css class for the tagged selector: `option.tagged {
    color: #FF0000;
}`

Comment: could you post relevant code?

Comment: select.selectedIndex=-1

Comment: As i understand your issue, you should look at a custom select element as native select element, especially the dropdown part, is not really customizable and quite impossible to make it cross browser

Comment: @roasted - Code posted.  Important to note that this is not a drop down list, but an actual select list where many options are visible at once and you are able to scroll through them.

Comment: @mplungjan - Afraid that doesn't work in my case.  I lose the selection on the current `<option>` and when selected again, the foreground color goes back to white.  I need to somehow change the styling on a selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to work for me:  (tested in chrome)

http://jsfiddle.net/y9Rz8/

```
$('#ctl00_Searcher_lbResults').on('change', function () {
    $(this).find('option:selected').addClass('tagged').siblings().removeClass('tagged');
    this.selectedIndex = -1
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't suit my needs.  A tagged item is not always the selected item, so I can't set the selected index of the `<select>` element to -1.  I need to retain the normal functionality of a select list, but simply change the forecolor to red whether an item is selected or not.

Comment: Additionally, the foreground color needs to stay red when the item is clicked (normal behavior is that the background turns blue and the foreground white).